# Mozilla FireFox hover works differently than in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have custom dropdown. Mostly all work is done using css. This dropdown is open/close by adding removing `ui-dropdown-expanded` class

Here is all my code

```js
$(document).on('click', '#ResponseFilter', function() {
  $(this).find('ul').toggleClass('ui-dropdown-expanded');
});
```

```css
.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown {
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-image: none;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position-x: 0%;
  background-position-y: 0%;
  background-repeat-x: ;
  background-repeat-y: ;
  background-size: auto;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-image-outset: 0px;
  border-image-repeat: stretch;
  border-image-slice: 100%;
  border-image-source: none;
  border-image-width: 1;
  border-left-color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(42, 100, 150);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant-caps: normal;
  font-variant-ligatures: normal;
  font-variant-numeric: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  position: relative;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 200px;
  word-break: keep-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.ui-dropdown:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-dropdown {
  background: #2D72A7;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin: 7px 10px 7px 0;
  border: 1px solid #2D72A7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.fl {
  float: left !important;
}

.fr {
  padding-top: 0;
  float: right !important;
}

.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown ul.ui-dropdown-expanded {
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown ul.ui-dropdown-expanded li,
.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown ul.ui-dropdown-expanded {
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
  color: #2a6496;
}

.ui-dropdown:hover ul.ui-dropdown-expanded {
  display: block;
  background: #1a4d74;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  top: 31px;
  border: 1px solid #113958;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.ui-dropdown ul {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown ul.ui-dropdown-expanded li {
  border-left: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
  border-right: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
}

.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown ul.ui-dropdown-expanded li,
.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown ul.ui-dropdown-expanded {
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
  color: #2a6496;
}

.ui-dropdown:hover ul.ui-dropdown-expanded li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #113958;
}

.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown ul.ui-dropdown-expanded li label {
  color: #2a6496;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.ui-dropdown:hover ul.ui-dropdown-expanded li label {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-dropdown ul li label {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ResponseFilter" class="ui-dropdown fl reviews-filter" style="width: 200px;">
  <div class="fl">
    <span id="response-filter-selected-value">All Responses Types</span>
  </div>
  <div class="fr" data-filter="response">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    <ul class="ui-dropdown-expanded">
      <li>
        <label for="response-filter-allresponsetypes">All Responses Types</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="response-filter-postedresponses">Posted Responses</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="response-filter-responserequired">Response Required</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

In snippet, it's a bit different than in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zd6363cq/2/) (don't know why cause code the same)

So problem - in FF especially there is some space between dropdown button and dropdown list, that make dropdown closed, cause user lost `:hover:`

On images, there are pointers where user can see dropdown list and not...

[image]
[image]

Is this issue because of margin, padding or what?
Thanks.

Comment: what actually you want `:hover` is working fine.

Comment: @MerajKhan, in my example there are some space, that loose `:hover` ... I thought it can be because of `margin` or `padding`, but it isn't... it is very tiny space... it is very hard to find that place... but it exists

Comment: Remove margin from `.ui-dropdown` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, issue was because of `1px` of `margin`.

Moving dropdown list a bit higher adding `-1px;` to existing margin to class `ui-dropdown-expanded` solve my problem.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#ResponseFilter', function() {
  $(this).find('ul').toggleClass('ui-dropdown-expanded');
});
```

```css
.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown {
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-image: none;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position-x: 0%;
  background-position-y: 0%;
  background-repeat-x: ;
  background-repeat-y: ;
  background-size: auto;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-image-outset: 0px;
  border-image-repeat: stretch;
  border-image-slice: 100%;
  border-image-source: none;
  border-image-width: 1;
  border-left-color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(42, 100, 150);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant-caps: normal;
  font-variant-ligatures: normal;
  font-variant-numeric: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  position: relative;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 200px;
  word-break: keep-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.ui-dropdown:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-dropdown {
  background: #2D72A7;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin: 7px 10px 7px 0;
  border: 1px solid #2D72A7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.fl {
  float: left !important;
}

.fr {
  padding-top: 0;
  float: right !important;
}

.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown ul.ui-dropdown-expanded {
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown ul.ui-dropdown-expanded li,
.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown ul.ui-dropdown-expanded {
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
  color: #2a6496;
}

.ui-dropdown:hover ul.ui-dropdown-expanded {
  display: block;
  background: #1a4d74;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  top: 31px;
  border: 1px solid #113958;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.ui-dropdown ul {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown ul.ui-dropdown-expanded li {
  border-left: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
  border-right: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
}

.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown ul.ui-dropdown-expanded li,
.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown ul.ui-dropdown-expanded {
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
  color: #2a6496;
}

.ui-dropdown:hover ul.ui-dropdown-expanded li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #113958;
}

.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown ul.ui-dropdown-expanded li label {
  color: #2a6496;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.ui-dropdown:hover ul.ui-dropdown-expanded li label {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-dropdown ul li label {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.reviews-filter.ui-dropdown ul.ui-dropdown-expanded {
  margin-top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ResponseFilter" class="ui-dropdown fl reviews-filter" style="width: 200px;">
  <div class="fl">
    <span id="response-filter-selected-value">All Responses Types</span>
  </div>
  <div class="fr" data-filter="response">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    <ul class="ui-dropdown-expanded">
      <li>
        <label for="response-filter-allresponsetypes">All Responses Types</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="response-filter-postedresponses">Posted Responses</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="response-filter-responserequired">Response Required</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```